# Can I use adb to call the "package installer" to install the application? adb install is not allowed

Tags: android, apk, adb

I tried to use the following code, but reported to me "shell does not declare android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES"

```
 adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW  -t "application/vnd.android.package-archive"  -d "file:///sdcard/Download/a.apk"
```

I am sad that for some reasons, adb install is not allowed, even if I run the following command, I still cannot install the application

```
adb shell settings put global verifier_verify_adb_installs 0
adb shell settings put global package_verifier_enable 0
```

log：Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_VERIFICATION_FAILURE: adb install not allowed!]

Comment: adb install xx.apk is not work! so sad.

Comment: I am looking for other ways to install the apk, because there is no app store and file manager, I cannot directly select the apk file through any app

Comment: does `adb install xx.apk` show an error message ? You can also sometimes find clues in the logcat

Comment: @BWT Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_VERIFICATION_FAILURE: adb install not allowed!]